# Subset list: Find only exact matches in Python

Tags: python, string, substring

This is my list:

```
smalllist = ['191010.National Geographic','191010.PRO7MAXX', '191010.PRO7', "191022.PRO7MAXX", "191022.PRO7"]


list(filter(lambda x: x.find("PRO7") > -1, smalllist))
```

I wanted to use this method to only get the exact matches in the list. Important: I tried it also with index but this only gave me the first match. I need ALL EXACT matches of the SUBSTRING.

```
Output: ['191010.PRO7MAXX', '191010.PRO7', '191022.PRO7MAXX', '191022.PRO7']
Desired Output: ['191010.PRO7','191022.PRO7']
```

How can I this done? :/

Comment: A little example: https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user304_Qzod0ICMOA_0.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use

```
[element for element in smalllist if element.split('.')[1]=='PRO7']
```

that way, it will work even if you have something like '1245.UNPRO7'

Comment: The split solutions works better for me, thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for the [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) operator.

Try using
`[x for x in smalllist if x.endswith("PRO7")]`